# Bluetooth module and an Android app

Tags: encryption, android, bluetooth

I have few sensors, a microcontroller with a bluetooth module and an android app to visualize the data.

- how can I make sure my system only connects to phones that activated bluetooth through the app?
- Is there a specific method to achieve this?
- My data is just a bunch of numbers. Should I use encryption? Is there any risk if I don't?

Comment: You have asked 2 very different questions. One is a pure programming question and not on topic here. The question about encryption and risk is unanswerable without an understanding of the data, the threats, and the impacts of misuse/abuse.

Comment: There's no way in android. Let any bluetooth device to connect but authenticate your client after association. Bluetooth has encryption.